# Tar produces different files each time

Tags: files, tar, hashsum

I often have large directories that I want to transfer to a local computer from a server. Instead of using recursive `scp` or `rsync` on the directory itself, I'll often `tar` and `gzip` it first and then transfer it.

Recently, I've wanted to check that this is actually working so I ran md5sum on two independently generated `tar` and `gzip` archives of the same source directory. To my suprise, the MD5 hash was different. I did this two more times and it was always a new value. Why am I seeing this result? Are two tar and gzipped directories both generated with the same version of GNU tar in the exact same way not supposed to be exactly the same?

For clarity, I have a source directory and a destination directory. In the destination directory I have dir1 and dir2. I'm running:

```
tar -zcvf /destination/dir1/source.tar.gz source && md5sum /destination/dir1/source.tar.gz >> md5.txt

tar -zcvf /destination/dir2/source.tar.gz source && md5sum /destination/dir2/source.tar.gz >> md5.txt
```

Each time I do this, I get a different result from md5sum. Tar produces no errors or warnings.

Comment: As you mentioned large directories, there is no excuse to not substitute `lbzip` or `7z` for `gzip` these days. This is not going to address your original question, but at least speed up compression by parallel threads.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the looks of things you’re probably being bitten by [`gzip` timestamps](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/TimestampsInGzipHeaders); to avoid those, run

```
GZIP=-n tar -zcvf ...
```

Note that to get fully reproducible tarballs, you should also impose [the sort order used by `tar`](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/FileOrderInTarballs):

```
GZIP=-n tar --sort=name -zcvf ...
```

If your version of `tar` doesn’t support `--sort`, use this instead:

```
find source -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z | GZIP=-n tar --no-recursion --null -T - -zcvf ...
```

Comment: I was trying to reproduce this with `tar -czf - dir | md5sum` but failed to get varying checksums. Was that because I was writing to a pipe? (No it wasn't, it turns out, but because of something else relating to not using Linux presumably)

Comment: @Kusalananda perhaps OpenBSD `tar` behaves differently... On Debian I get different sums when piping too.

Comment: I used GNU `tar` 1.29, but `gzip` comes from my base system... hmm... but that got the `-n` option as well. Oh well.

Comment: Can I also add following `--mode=a+rwX --owner=0 --group=0 --numeric-owner` due to set defualt file permissions of the files? @Stephen Kitt

Comment: @alper of course, you can add whatever other options you want.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac @stephen-kitt's answer didn't work for me, not exactly sure why but when I separated the gzip from the tar command it started producing the same hash. Here's what I ended up with:

```
outputpath="$(pwd)/folder_to_zip" 
find "$outputpath" -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z | tar -s "#$outputpath/##" --no-recursion --null -T - -cf - | gzip -n > "$outputpath.tar.gz" && md5 "$outputpath.tar.gz"
```