# Why does the PIGZ produce a different md5sum

Tags: files, tar, hashsum

I observe that when I use `PIGZ` version, generated tar file's `md5sum` hash is different than the next one generated.

Instead of `PIGZ=-n` if I use `GZIP=-n` generated hashes are same. I have followed following answer for [Tar produces different files each time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438330/198423).

```
$ find sourceCode -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z | PIGZ=-n tar \
--mode=a+rwX --owner=0  --group=0 --absolute-names --no-recursion --null -T - -zcvf file.tar.gz
$ md5sum file.tar.gz # some hash is generated

# When I apply the same operation above output for md5sum file.tar.gz is different
```

=> Is this a normal case? or is it possible to have same behavior for `PIGZ` like `GZIP`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `tar` to use `pigz`, you need to ask it to do so:

```
... | PIGZ=-n tar -Ipigz --mode=a+rwX --owner=0  --group=0 --absolute-names --no-recursion --null -T - -cvf file.tar.gz
```

With the `-Ipigz` option, and without `-z`, `tar` uses `pigz` and the `PIGZ` variable is taken into account. This results in tarballs with the same contents as `gzip`-compressed archives with `GZIP=-n`.

Comment: Also is it neccesary for me to use `--mode=a+rwX --owner=0  --group=0 --absolute-names` parametes in addition to your answer on `tar produces different files each time.`

Comment: That’s a somewhat different question; the answer depends on what variability you want to allow. You need to set the owner/group if you want to allow different users to build your tarball and still produce the same tarball.

Comment: When I add a character and remove a character from the file I am tarring, even the data's hash is same, its zipped hash differs. I am not sure what may be the real cause of it or is it a normal behavior. Please see as a new question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630736/how-to-create-a-deterministic-tar-gz-using-tar